# Compare 2 tables and find the missing record

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have 2 database tables:

`customers` and `customers_1`

I have 100 customers in the `customers` table but only 99 customers in the `customers_1` table. I would like to write a query that will compare the 2 tables and will result in the missing row.

I have tried this following SQL:

`select * from customers c where in (select * from customers_1)`

But this will only check for the one table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query shouldn't work this way. You have to compare one column to another and use `NOT IN` instead of `IN`:

```
select * 
from customers c 
where customerid not in (select customerid from customers_1)
```

However, Since you are on SQL Server 2008, you can use [`EXCEPT`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx):

```
SELECT * FROM customers
EXCEPT 
SELECT * FROM customers_1;
```

This will give you the rows which are in the `customers` table that are not in `customers_1` table:

> EXCEPT returns any distinct values from the left query that are not
>   also found on the right query.

Answer (score 2):

This is easy. Just join them with a left outer join and check for `NULL` in the table which has the 99 rows. It will look something like this.

```
SELECT * FROM customers c
LEFT JOIN customers1 c1 ON c.some_key = c1.some_key
WHERE c1.some_key IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of NOT IN clause consider using NOT EXISTS. NOT EXISTS clause performs better in this particular scenario. Your query would look like:

```
SELECT * FROM Customer c WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Customer_1 c1 WHERE c.Customer_Id = c1.Customer_Id)
```

SELECT 1 is just for readability so everyone will know that I don't care about the actual data.